# How to do regression testing of code which relies heavily on SP... classes?

Tags: testing, unit-testing

I've inherited a SharePoint project and I'm at the step when I will start adding tests for regression testing. The fact that practically every method in the project relies on `SPSite` and similar `SP...` classes means that I have to mock SharePoint classes within the tests.

Microsoft's SharePoint.Emulators library [is not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31806850/240613), since the project uses .NET Framework 4.5. On the other hand, [SPEmulators](http://writeabout.net/2014/06/21/spemulators-available-on-nuget/) works well.

The only problem is that as soon as the code goes a bit deeper within SharePoint structure, it hits `null`s within the mocks. For instance, this is the beginning of the method I try to test right now:

```
public void Demo(SPSite site)
{
    List<SPAlternateUrl> urls = site.WebApplication.AlternateUrls.ToList();
    ...
}
```

Site exists—this is the actual emulated object—and so does `site.WebApplication`, but `site.WebApplication.AlternateUrls` is `null`, so the method throws an exception as soon as it begins.

Since the tests are done like this:

```
using (var context = new SPEmulationContext(IsolationLevel.Fake))
{
    Sample1.Demo(context.site);
    ...
}
```

there is no way to change the objects at their initialization (like in Microsoft Fakes), and since `AlternateUrls` is `readonly`, I suppose that it cannot be changed later either.

One option is to modify the method to do the needed checks. I don't want to start changing the code which has currently 0% branch coverage.

What are my options?

How is done the regression testing of legacy code which relies too much on `SP...` classes?